# Вывести подписи на фотографиях

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно вывести подписи на фото справа внизу вне зависимости от ширины, высоты и выравнивания изображения?

Есть такая разметка, которая генерируется php + js:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img class="img-left" src="img.jpg">

  <div class="copyright">
    "Иван Иваныч"
  </div>
</div>
```

На данный момент пока 3 класса для изображений:
 1. на всю ширину колонки (700px) **без** float 
 2. float left, ширина 350px
 3. float right, ширина 350px

Пример необходимого результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `img-wrap` - делается `position:relative` а `copyright` - `position:absolute` и выравнивается по нужному краю/углу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 350px;
}
.copyright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
}
.img-left {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img class="img-left" src="http://bbeautyworld.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/break_dancing_hedgehog_by_raharris2-d5ww1w6.jpg">

    <div class="copyright">
      Иван Иваныч
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```